# how can react native application communicate with PC or Laptop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

i want to communicate with PC using react native via Wifi or Bluetooth. i want to send file from react native application to PC using React Native. I don't know how to do this. Is there any library to do this. basically i am building a wireless mouse and keyboard in which user can operate his/her PC from an Application.
Attach any reference or pictures if you have some.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HOrnnQYpwc) from the React Native EU conference, particularly from 20´30. This will help you get started on the basics from a React Native perspective.

Look too at something like [this](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v11.0.0%2Fble_sdk_app_hid_keyboard_pairing_nfc.html) for the more in-depth details around building an HID peripheral (which is essentially what you are planning to do.

There are a number of react native sdks for BLE on GitHub. Check them out, for example: https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager

Alternatively you could communicate over wifi using [websockets](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket-support).

The BLE approach is, as the name suggests, the preferable approach in terms of energy usage, but you might get started faster with web sockets.

There is also [this](https://github.com/pelya/android-keyboard-gadget), which may provide inspiration. Good luck.